# C99 printf formatters vs C++11 user-defined-literals

Tags: c++, c++11, printf, c99, code-translation

This code:

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
   uint64_t val=1234567890;
   printf("%"PRId64"\n",val);
   exit(0);
}
```

Works for [C99](http://ideone.com/Lo5Jw), [C++03](http://ideone.com/qf0QW), [C++11 according to GCC 4.5](http://ideone.com/DO8Zq), but fails on [C++11 according to GCC 4.7.1](http://liveworkspace.org/code/53b31b6e9b51bdc0101cacb07719977b). Adding a space before `PRId64` lets GCC 4.7.1 compile it.

Which one is correct?

Comment: actually, you need PRIu64, not PRId64, to print unsigned (in general PRI{o,u,x,X}N for unsigned, and PRI{i,d}N for signed)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

gcc 4.7.1 is correct.  According to the standard,

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> #### 2.2 Phases of translation [lex.phases]
>
> 1 - The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is speciﬁed by the following 
>   phases. [...] 
>   3. The source ﬁle is decomposed into preprocessing tokens (2.5) and sequences of white-space characters
>   (including comments). [...]
>   4. Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, [...]

And per **2.5 Preprocessing tokens [lex.pptoken]**, *user-deﬁned-string-literal* is a preprocessing token production:

> #### 2.14.8 User-deﬁned literals [lex.ext]
>
> *user-deﬁned-string-literal*:
>       *string-literal ud-suffix*
>   *ud-suffix*:
>       *identifier*

So the phase-4 macro expansion of `PRId64` is irrelevant, because `"%"PRId64` has already been parsed as a single *user-deﬁned-string-literal* preprocessing token consisting of *string-literal* `"%"` and *ud-suffix* `PRId64`.

Oh, this is going to be *awesome*; everyone will have to change

```
printf("%"PRId64"\n", val);
```

to

```
printf("%" PRId64"\n", val);     // note extra space
```

---

However!  gcc and clang have agreed to treat user-defined string literals without a leading underscore on the suffix as two separate tokens (per the non well formedness criterion), see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52538 so for future versions of gcc (4.8 branch, I think) existing code will work again.

Comment: But how on earth can a user-defined literal be defined/parsed *before* platform ifdef's are processed? UDL can do all `constexpr` stuff, right?

Comment: @rubenvb that's fine; `constexpr` is a phase-7 process.

Comment: @rubenvb: but the UDL will be gone by then, due to preprocessor macro replacement in phase 4.

Comment: @rubenvb if it helps you understand, `"lit"_udl` is treated as `operator "" _udl("lit", 3)`; this happens early in phase 7.

Comment: but by the time that happens, in this example, you `_udl` is already replaced by the preprocessor...

Comment: @rubenvb ah right; there's nothing there for macro replacement to hit; `"%"PRId64` is a *single* token.

Comment: Ick. IMHO writing it with spaces: `printf("%" PRId64 "\n", val);` is better style anyway, but it's still a change that breaks existing code. Incidentally, ud-suffixes not starting with an underscore are reserved for future standardization, so the program is "ill-formed, no diagnostic required". Reference: [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 2.14.8p10 and 17.6.4.3.5

Comment: @rubenvb this has caused some discussion and there is a fix in the works; see my latest edit.

Comment: Good for gcc and clang -- but the code is still ill-formed as far as the language standard is concerned, and other compilers won't necessarily do the same thing. The bug report mentions that the committee is considering this issue. Also `<inttypes.h>` is probably the most common source of this problem, but other code could also be  broken by the change.

Comment: "lit"_udl is a single token in C++11.  So it precedes the preprocessor.

Comment: Sorry if I'm repeating but is adding the space the solution for this? Is it guaranteed not to change the behaviour?

Comment: @HannaKhalil yes, adding the space is the solution and will work on all compilers (since compile-time string concatenation works however much whitespace there is). Omitting the space was only ever a stylistic matter.