# g++ 4.7 evaluates operator "" as sibling to macro expansion

Tags: c++, compilation, user-defined-literals, gcc4.7

I'm moving some code over to GCC 4.7 (from 4.6) and ran into a few compiler errors and found the problem documented in the [GCC 4.7 porting guide](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/porting_to.html):

> ### User-defined literals and whitespace
>
> The C++ compiler in ISO C11 mode `std={c++11,c++0x,gnu++11,gnu++0x}`
>   supports user defined literals, which are incompatible with some valid
>   ISO C++03 code.
>
> In particular, whitespace is now needed after a string literal and
>   before something that could be a valid user defined literal. Take the
>   valid ISO C++03 code
>
> ```
> const char *p = "foobar"__TIME__;
> ```
>
> In C++03, the **TIME** macro expands to some string literal and is
>   concatenated with the other one. In C++11 `__TIME__` isn't expanded,
>   instead `operator "" __TIME__` is being looked up, resulting in the
>   following diagnostic:
>
> ```
> error: unable to find string literal operator  ‘operator"" __TIME__’
> ```
>
> This applies to any string literal followed without whitespace by some
>   macro. To fix, just add some whitespace between the string literal and
>   the macro name.

While I could fix the errors, I'd like to know *why* I must do this. `__TIME__` is a macro, so `"something"__TIME__` would change into `"something""15:52:03"` (or similar) in the preprocessing stage, so the compiler would never have the opportunity to see it as `operator ""`.

Is this behavior standards-approved or is it a bug?

Comment: `"xxx"yyy` is a single token in C++11, while it was two seperate token in C++03, which means the `__TIME__` macro is never detected as such.

Comment: Just recently discussed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869593/c99-printf-formatters-vs-c11-user-defined-literals

Comment: This is how user-defined literals work (as mentioned in the docs you quoted). The C++11 standard specifically calls this out as a breaking change (Appendix C.2.1). If you want to compile your code with a C++11 compiler mode, you'll need to change your source to fix the breaking change that C++11 made.  If you don't want to change your source code, I think you'll have to tell g++ to use `-std=c++98` or `-std=gnu++98`.

Comment: Looks like there is a documentation bug, it should say "The C++ compiler in ISO C++11 mode", since [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) is a very different beast.  The new behavior of the actual compiler is correct though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that `"foobar"__TIME__` is no longer tokenized into the preprocessor tokens `"foobar"` followed by `__TIME__`.

Preprocessor tokens "have the lexical form of a keyword, an identifier, a literal, an operator, or a punctuator." The addition of user defined literals changes what is lexed as a preprocessor token. Now `"foobar"__TIME__` is a single *user-defined-character-literal* preprocessor token, and so when phase 4 of translation occurs, which would replace `__TIME__` with the `"15:52:03"`, there is no `__TIME__` token to get replaced this way.

Yes, this behavior is specified in the standard.

Due to the cinttypes macros it looks like more code is affected by this than the committee realized and they are considering addressing it. Some compilers are already moving to handle problems with cinttypes, however not in a way that would fix this use of `__TIME__` for you. I think your best bet is to just change the code.