# Is there any difference between QString& and QString &?

Tags: c++, qt

Please see the space between QString and &. I am wondering in QT, is there any difference between QString& and QString &?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no difference. It is pure C++ Syntax. C++ can be considered a white space independent language. Some discussion on that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293205/c-is-a-white-space-independent-language-exception-to-the-rule)

Comment: `&` in this context is not an operator, and regardless, precedence does not affect whether white space is relevant at all.

Comment: You are right. Didn't mean that to be a causality. I thought QString had the operator defined, which - you are right - is not the case. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Even if it _did_ have `operator&` defined, `QString&` would still be a reference to a QString.

Answer (score 0):

What c_k says is correct.

Note that with Qt's signals and slots, you can omit some of the syntax:

```
public slots:
    // Full syntax here
    void setName(const QString &name);
```

then:

```
// This is OK and Qt knows to connect the slot
connect(ui->nameEdit, SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), this, SLOT(setName(QString)));
```

In fact the extra characters and spaces just make the connect call take a lot longer to execute.