# C++11 and C++ 2003 compatibility

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

Does anybody has a list of potential problems when rebuilding C++ 2003 code with a C++11 compiler?
Maybe some compilers have compatibility warnings.

Comment: `auto` changed meaning, `auto_ptr` disappeared.

Comment: @K-ballo Oops, thanks for catching that. I haven't used it in a while.

Comment: You should check Appendix C.2 of the C++11 standard.

Comment: @Antimony `auto_ptr` is still in C++11. It's only deprecated, not removed.

Comment: I have been bitten by this breaking change in C++11: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909806/g-4-7-evaluates-operator-as-sibling-to-macro-expansion

Comment: You mustn't specify any template parameters explicitly for `std::make_pair` and such like. It's the "deserves to be broken" kind of change, since that was already true in C++03.