# Compile error using gcc - strprintf("%"PRId64, n)

Tags: c++, gcc, centos6.5

I am trying to compile some code from Github on my, (up to date), Centos 6.5 using GCC++.
But I get the error message below when I try to compile the code.

The line below is the one failing:

```
...
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS 1

...
#include <inttypes.h>

...
inline std::string i64tostr(int64_t n)
{
  return strprintf("%"PRId64, n);   // <-- errors here.
}

...
```

And the error is:

```
error: expected ')' before 'PRId64
```

What could be the issue and how do I resolve it?

**Edit 1:** This is the line of code failing.
https://github.com/rat4/blackcoin/blob/master/src/util.h#L226

**Edit 2:** replacing the code with *printf("%" PRId64, n);* (note the extra space), as suggested in the proposed answer does not work, (the same error message is given).

Comment: It works OK for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3aff44dd52c22be - are you sure you have all the relevant #includes ? Any warnings or other issues in the preceding lines ?

Comment: This - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869593/c99-printf-formatters-vs-c11-user-defined-literals - is an answer

Comment: BTW, it would be better (for future) to include the compiler version and compile parameters in a question

Comment: I added the link to the github code. As I said, I have Centos 6.5 all up to date including GCC

Comment: What is `strprintf` ? Can you post a MCVE?

Comment: Looking further up in the source file, there is suggestion that perhaps your compiler doesn't support inttypes.h properly, add in `#ifndef PRId64` `#error Lame compiler detected` `#endif`

Comment: @MattMcNabb, the error does trigger, so that implies that something might have gone wrong somewhere in my install of gcc (?).
I have version 4.7.2, is there somewhere I could re-install inttypes.h?

Comment: @FFMG are you using -std=c++11 flag in compiling? It's help to change your code to a MCVE, and also post your commandline for compiling it

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the error is somewhere outer. Look - http://ideone.com/dqeMTY - I copied your code, **but** I mistaked and missed `#` sign before `define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS 1`, and ... I've got the same error near `PRId64`. Try to comment a half of code before suspicious line, then another half and so on.